# GitHub and Visual Studio Community 2015 - Error trying to push

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am a contributor in a Git repository where we are trying to share and work on a Visual Studio project, and I am using the Git extension to interface it to Git. I have added some files to the project and from the extension and there is an incoming commit. When I try to push my commit under outgoing commit, this error pops up:

[image]

> **Translation** it is not possible to push branch master to the repository origin because there are new commits on the remote. It is not possible to perform a fast-forward merge with the branch on the remote repository.

How can i fix it?

Comment: The error message you see is in different language than English. Make sure that you can commit your changes **first** without using VS and see if it works or not.

Comment: Also try to use GitHub Extension for Visual Studio for your operations going on.

Answer (score 0):

If my wife's translation of the Italian is correct then the problem is that you have incoming commits from the remote repository and that you need to perform a Pull (& Merge) before you can Push your changes to the remote.

Alternatively you could perform a Fetch and then rebase your local changes on top of origin/master.